# Laravel custom auth route issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I tried to make custom Auth routes for my app because I needed to use a referral system and the default auth wouldn't let users register with referral links so I've made a custom one, now I can register with refellal link and save the id of the user in a new user table as referred person. But the issue is I cannot register without referral link now. It keeps refreshing the register page, I guess there is a problem with the register form `action` link but i'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my `AuthController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\User;
use Cookie;
use Guard;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('guest');
  }

  // Show register form
  public function showRegisterForm(Request $request)
  {
    $user = User::where('affiliate_id',$request->query('ref'))->first();
    $referred_by = count($user) > 0 ? $user->id : '';
    return view('auth.register',compact('referred_by'));
  }

  protected function validator(array $data)
  {
      return Validator::make($data, [
          'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
          'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
          'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
      ]);
  }

  protected function create(array $data)
  {
      return User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'username' => $data['username'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
          'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
          'referred_by' => $data['referred_by'],
      ]);
  }

  public function register(Request $request, $referred_by=0)
  {
    $request->merge(['referred_by' => $referred_by]);
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $this->create($request->all());

    Auth::attempt($request->only('username','password'));
    return redirect()->to('/home');

  }
}
```

Here is my register form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/register/{{$referred_by}}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
      @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>
      @if ($errors->has('username'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
      @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
      @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  @captcha()
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Register
      </button>
      <a href="{{route('login')}}" class="btn btn-warning">
        Already member?
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I also have roles and I need to define default role for users who just register so doesn't need i give them role manually.

Update:

```
Route::get('/login',['as'=>'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
Route::post('/login', ['uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@login']);
Route::get('/logout',['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
Route::get('/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthController@showRegisterForm']);
Route::post('/register/{referred_by?}', 'AuthController@register');
Route::post('password/email', ['as'=>'password.email', 'uses'=>'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
Route::get('password/reset', ['as'=>'password.request', 'uses'=>'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
Route::post('password/reset', ['as'=>'password.request', 'uses'=>'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as'=>'password.reset', 'uses'=>'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
Route::post('logout', ['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
```

Comment: have you tried to change LoginPath variable in Auth Controller 
protected $loginPath = 'myAwesomeUrl';
[link] (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/changing-login-url-default-on-laravel?page=1)

Comment: @SaadBhutto login is working just fine, and i'm sure is not about login because my issue is user will not register and not login the user.

Comment: Can you add the route definition to the question please?

Comment: @Scopey updated.

Comment: change {referred_by?}   to {referred_by} Only ,

Comment: @SaadBhutto no it doesn't work still refreshing register page without register user

Comment: Are you assigning reffered_by=0 to request which doesn't have referal link..?

Comment: @ZaheerAttar yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small thing you need to change.

```
$referred_by = count($user) > 0 ? $user->id : '';
```

Replace this line with

```
$referred_by = count($user) > 0 ? $user->id : 0;
```

**Solution Explaination**

When you are passing `''` to `reffered_by`, it is considered nothing and URL would look like `www.example.com/register` and

```
Route::get('/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthController@showRegisterForm']);
```

this route gets hit and it shows registration form again, When you actually want

```
Route::post('/register/{referred_by?}', 'AuthController@register');
```

this route to get hit. So avoid passing `''` and pass `0`, so URL would look like `www.example.com/register/0` and it will hit correct route and do what you want.